# John The Ripper выдает ошибку "No password hashes loaded". John не распознает хэши

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Я пытаюсь взломать пароль с помощью утилиты John The Ripper на kali linux.
С помощью unshadow создала файл паролей:

```
$ unshadow /etc/passwd /etc/shadow > passwd.txt
```

После этого я выполняю команду:

```
$ john passwd.txt
```

Но вылетает ошибка: Using default input encoding: UTF-8 No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать... Перекодировка файла на UTF-8 не помогла.

Comment: А если попробовать ломануть не стандартный файл с паролями линукс, а просто файл содержащий хэш?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1217593/505198, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48091220/5430535 видела?

Comment: Может все-таки подумал? Как тебе такое @don Rumata :-)

Comment: @em0ji, я не распарсил о чём ты. Можно подробнее?